# Change divs (hide/reveal) on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help.

I have this:

```
<div class="slides">

  <div class="slide 1">
     Content here.
  </div>

  <div class="slide 2">
     Content Here.
  </div>

  <div class="slide 3">
     Content Here.
  </div>

</div>
```

I need to swap **div 1** with **div 2** on mousescroll down or with **slide 3** on mousescroll up, hiding an active div and revealing the neighbour one with a transition effect.

I'm not fluent with javascript, is there a simple solution?

Comment: This is not a get code for free site.

Comment: And that's not what I'm asking for, keep this kind of comments to yourself.

I can't find any related topic on stackoverflow and that's why I ask, some people already did it and know the most efficient ways to achieve that.

Comment: But it is. If you don't try some code yourself, then you are asking others to make it for you. Since you aren't paying them, you would be, by definition, "getting code for free."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone searches for a fulfillment for a similar need:

[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) does the job and they have a lean build that doesn't require jquery (in downloadable files, 5kb gzipped).

I don't care about if it's considered an answer or not, it just works and helped me a lot. I will be grateful to read more on subject and get more educated.